# Verilog always vs assign

Tags: verilog, synopsys-vcs

Is it legal for a simulator to evaluate `clk_out1` in the next active Verilog scheduling window w.r.t `clk`? `clk_out2` seems to be updated in the same scheduling window as `clk`.

```
reg clk_out1;
always @(*)
    clk_out1 = clk;

assign clk_out2 = clk;
```

In this image
Red - NBA region
Yellow - Active region
[image]

Comment: Updated with waveform. Question is why there is a mismatch in how VCS is evaluating `clk_out1` and `clk_out2`

Comment: the out2 signal should *not* be updated in the nba region. It needs to be assigned with <= for that. This could be a result of an optimization though. Both out1 and out2 shoudl be evaluated in the active region which follows the #0 and nba region.There could be as many active regions as needed to evaluate all outsanding events.

Answer (score 0):

The Verilog scheduling semantics dictate that both assignments happen in the same active scheduling region. They will behave as if `clk`, `clk_out1` and `clk_out2` are aliases for each other. This is assuming you used a regular blocking assignment and not a non-blocking assignment to `clk_out1`, which is the recommended way of assigning clocks in RTL.